# How to use the np where using the different np shape

Tags: python, numpy, image-segmentation

I wanna use the code more efficiently.

and I'm now converting the color of the image by referring to the value of the image form

As many people know, it is related to image segmentation.

I got the class value of the Image [Width]*[Height] through a deep learning model.

And I'd like to draw the segmented area in its original color, and the other in gray

Below is my result. the human part is the segmented area

[image]

```
def read_video_frame(video_path):

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        frame = cv2.resize(frame, dsize=(448, 448), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

        image = np.array(frame)

        mask = model_run(image)  # Deep learning model 

        gray = skimage.color.gray2rgb(skimage.color.rgb2gray(image)) * 255

        if mask is None:
            segmented_image = gray.astype(np.uint8)
        else:
            segmented_image[:, :, 0] = np.where(mask >= 1, image[:, :, 0], gray[:, :, 0])
            segmented_image[:, :, 1] = np.where(mask >= 1, image[:, :, 1], gray[:, :, 1])
            segmented_image[:, :, 2] = np.where(mask >= 1, image[:, :, 2], gray[:, :, 2])

        cv2.imshow('video', segmented_image)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
```

And you will find an uncomfortable part of the code in the image.

For example, I got the class value of (5*5) through a deep learning model

The form of the NumPy array is as follows.

```
ex = np.array([[0,0,1,0,0],
               [0,1,1,1,1],
               [0,0,1,1,1],
               [0,0,0,2,2],
               [0,0,1,2,2]
                          ])
```

If the value of the array was greater than 1, the original image value would be used, and if it was 0, the image value of gray would be used.

So, I wanted to use np.where() to deal with it all at once.

```
segmented_image[:, :] = np.where(mask >= 1, image[:, :], gray[:, :])
```

But I got the this error

> **ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (448,448) (448,448,3) (448,448,3)**
>
> (My target image size is 448x448)

Because as you know, the image pixel's NumPy shape is (width, height, 3).

So I was forced to divide into three parts of r,g,b, and form an image.

```
segmented_image[:, :, 0] = np.where(mask >= 1, image[:, :, 0], gray[:, :, 0])
segmented_image[:, :, 1] = np.where(mask >= 1, image[:, :, 1], gray[:, :, 1])
segmented_image[:, :, 2] = np.where(mask >= 1, image[:, :, 2], gray[:, :, 2])
```

How can I write the code more clearly?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: @wwii Yes, sorry! I attached the code of the image. But before, I had written a separate section about what I was curious about. Don't be so angry :)

Comment: Add another dimension to the boolean array so it will [broadcast](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) - `mask=mask>=0; new= np.where(mask[:,:,None],image,gray)`

Comment: I wasn't (am not) angry.